# Debug mock services generated by soapUI

Tags: web-services, debugging, apache-axis, soapui, fault

preconditions:
**1.** response(generated as mock service) in soupUI
**2.** web-client, that knows about running mock service by address:

```
http://localhost:8091/cps/axis2/services/
```

Mock services are running OK.

When perform request from web-client,I expect to get response as specified in soapUI.
Instead of this I got general error:

```
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
```

That means there are problems with response,thus html with 500 code returned.

The question is ,how can I debug what is the cause of problem?
I suspect namespaces and abstract types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bad endpoint on the client. i.e. it's not using the right URI.  Or, the mockservice may be configured but not running. In this situation, SoapUI responds with an HTML page that says something like:

"There are currently 0 running soapUI MockServices" or some such.

Take a look at your WSDL that SoapUI produces. Consume that in SoapUI and you should be able to send yourself a request, see it in the mockservice log, and get a response. Once you get that working, THEN try a client. And it should work. If it doesn't, check its endpiont vs the one that the SoapUI request (built from the SoapUI mock) used. Adjust for localhost vs IP address.

Comment: yes, it was really bad endpoint,actually it worked in browser, but didn't suie for mock services,such a dummy error.

Comment: about debugging,I'm looking in TCPmon

Comment: I'm getting this error as well, care to elaborate what a "bad endpoint" means?

Answer (score 0):

I might not be able to answer your question in general but in this case it looks like instead of returning fully specified response from soapUI mock (i.e. with soap:Envelope included) you only specify message body. The official documentation has [samples](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/simulating-complex-behaviour.html) that specify responses.

*P.S. I hope I got your question correctly*

Comment: response was specified ok, error was in endpoint,anyway thank you for suggestion,I'm  new in mocking